# ASP.NET MVC 3 Already contains a defenition for

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Me and my friend having a problem while doing a homework assignment.

We have made 4 print screens. The problem is we both get the same error"

The error is:
**Error 1 The type 'Jabber.Models.Jab' already contains a definition for 'Message'**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI60N.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0dkb.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Qko.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEW8t.png

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: @John Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100).

Comment: @Gilles tnx for pointing that out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class Jab is marked as partial, which means the compiler will combine it with any other classes named jab in the same namespace (as long as they're partial too).  Your EDMX file is in the same folder and has an entity called Jab, which will be turned into a class automatically.  It also has a property named Message, which is the reason you're getting the error.

Try using the MetaDataType attribute to add the metadata to message instead.

```
public class JabMetaData {
    [Display(Name = "Message")]...
    public string Message { get; set;}
}
[MetaDataType(typeof(JabMetaData)]
public partial class Jab {
}
```

Comment: Can you explain it a bit bigger?, We're trying but still not anything worked out.